# Pass data forward by Segue (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 view controller

1. Main has a button
2. Detail has a label: lblDetail

I'm trying to pass data by segue : "sgPushDetail". When click on the button on Main, the label on Detail will be changed.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sgPushDetail"]) {    
        DetailViewController *detail = segue.destinationViewController;
        detail.lblDetail.text = @"you've already clicked";   
    }        
}
```

But when i build, the label doesn't change. Please help me with this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DetailViewController` is not loaded when you are setting value for the label in `prepareForSegue` method. Do the following:

1. Create a property (i.e. `NSString`) in `DetailViewController`
2. Set the value for this property in prepareForSegue method
3. In `viewDidLoad` method of your `DetailViewController`, assign this property value to the label.